# Export Fbx from Blender To Unity

Tags: animation, export, unity-game-engine, blender, fbx

I have a complete blender file which has an animated character with two actions and I want to export it as an fbx so i can view it in unity.  I did it and for some reason it is only exporting my actions and not the mesh or camera or anything else only exports the actions.  Why is it not exporting my mesh I have everything selected and i have apply modifiers and include animation selected. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are exporting in Blender with *Selected Objects* options set. In this case you have to select the mesh itself in object mode to export both. Selecting the armature will export animations only.

If you do have a mesh in Unity3D but can't see it in the scene, you have to fix the scale factor. It's set to 0.01 by default. So change it to 1 to see the mesh in its original size.